# Memory Banks in Intel 8086 and 8088

Tags: memory, x86-16

Why do we need two memory banks in 8086 but just one single memory bank in 8088?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8086 is a 16-bit processor with a 16-bit memory bus. That requires a memory subsystem that can deliver 16-bits at a time, probably built using two sets of 8-bit memory chips.

The 8088 uses an 8-bit memory bus, to make it cheaper. It was designed to save on the minimum number of chips needed to build a system.

Comment: The speed could have been much better if two memory banks were used as it takes less cycles in case of aligned word. This is a major advantage according to me. Why did they preferred cost over speed?

Comment: "Customer demand" I guess. The original IBM PC used the 8088, but was quite successful anyway. :-)